# MQTT overriding the whole record in dynamoDB using an AWS IoT Rule Action

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, mqtt, aws-iot

I have an AWS IOT Core device. I have a rule for the MQTT broker when it gets a message for the specific topic; it updates the AWS dynamo DB record. At his moment it overrides the whole record. But I want to update only some part of the record. I just want to add one more key (and value) to the record which has primary key of 125. please check the image.

Thanks[image: Please check the image of action]

Comment: Well, how do you execute update api for the item? The image does not provide much useuful information.

Comment: Thanks for reply. right now i have node app that publish some data to mqtt broker. and action attached to broker, it is adding the data to dynamoDB automatically. i did not write code for update. It is built in AWS.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just want to add one more key (and value) to the record which has primary key of 125

If this means that you want to append to an existing array in an existing record then you cannot do this with an action in an AWS IoT Rule.

However you can add separate records with the same partition key of 125 if you use a sort key. The sort key could be obtained from the timestamp (or some other field in your payload that is unique for the same partition key).

Comment: Thanks ben. I will make different table for this.